# Canceling a task when the main thread has exited

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have a main thread that starts a task but does not wait for its completion. I also have a cancel button on the UI, on the click of which I would like to cancel the task. I tried doing this at multiple places in the method in the task:

```
if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
```

This however, does not seem to work in the desired way.

Earlier I thought of doing cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() but as far as I understand, this raises an exception, and I have no place in the main thread to catch this. What would be the best way to cancel the task in this scenario?

Comment: Show us the code of your task

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your `cancelToken` originally came from a `CancellationTokenSource` which the main thread still has access to. You should just be able to call:

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

in your cancel button's click event handler.

`ThrowIfCancellationRequested` will throw an exception in the task thread, not in the main thread. You would only see an exception in the main thread if you called `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` and then requested the `Result` in the main thread.

Note that if you just return after cancellation has been requested, your task's state will end up as `RanToCompletion` rather than `Canceled`. Calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is the preferred way of indicating cancellation, partly as it means if you've got a deep stack within your task's code, you don't need to worry about explicitly returning from each method.

I'm unsure whether cancellation represents a fault that needs to be observed, by the way - I *suspect* not, but you should probably check. (You should probably have a continuation to deal with errors anyway...)

Comment: I would also add that any ContinueWith(TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled) tasks expect an exception to be thrown in order to "fire".